# malformed type: ...using 'some-object' in this context is invalid

Tags: dart

I not sure what the problem is or what the runtime error is trying to tell me. I have a class that attempts to allocate an object during the class's construction, however, I get the following runtime error:

> malformed type: line 150 pos 26: using 'type_tree' in this context is invalid
>           **_output_type = new **t**ype_tree.asUnknown();**

So I added a test method on the class thinking I couldn't allocate during construction:

```
class X {
  X() {
    type_tree doh = new type_tree.asUnknown();    <--- runtime error
  }
  void bogus() {
    type_tree output_type = new type_tree.asUnknown();
  }
}
...
X x = new X();
x.bogus();    <-- runtime error as well
```

Yet I can allocate the **type_tree** object outside of the class just fine:

```
type_tree obj = new type_tree.asUnknown();    <-- works
```

I have never run into this type of runtime error before and can't figure out what the issue is. Any ideas on what to look for?

Below is a more detailed version of the code.

**type_tree.dart**

```
part of OpenCog.moses;
class type_tree extends NTree<type_node> {
  // Basic named constructors
  type_tree.asUnknown() {...}
  type_tree.asIllFormed() {...}

}
```

**procedure_call_base.dart**

```
part of OpenCog.moses;
class ProcedureCallBase extends operator_base {
  type_tree _output_type;
  factory ProcedureCallBase.from(...) {
     ProcedureCallBase(String name, int arity, combo_tree tr,
        [bool infer_type = false]) : super(name),
       _arity = arity,
       _body = tr {
       _output_type = new type_tree.asUnknown();  <-- runtime error
     }

    ...
    ProcedureCallBase v = new ProcedureCallBase(name, arity, tr, infer_type);
    return v;
  }
  // A test method called in unit test.
  void bogus() {
    type_tree output_type = new type_tree.asUnknown();  <-- also fails at runtime
  }

}
```

Unit test code:

```
    test("Check valid definition", () {
      String proc = r"add(2) := +($1 $2)";

      ProcedureCallBase v = new ProcedureCallBase.from(proc); <-- fails in the constructor
      v.bogus();   <-- fails inside bogus method
    });

    test("Check type tree", () {
      type_tree doh = new type_tree.asUnknown();  <-- this works.
    });
```

Basically for some reason I can't create a type_tree object while in the context of **ProcedureCallBase** and I don't know why.

*Dart build: 1.21.0-dev.11.2*

Comment: `type_tree.asUnknown` is probably just not imported. Can you please show how the class looks like, which file it is in and how you import it?

Comment: Updated question and added more code. Basically I can't create a type_tree object in any code within the ProcedureCallBase class yet I can create a type_tree object outside, for example during a unit test.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Doesn't the DartAnalyzer show any warnings or errors?

Comment: Where do you have these files. Are they all in the `lib` sub directory of your project directory (where `pubspec.yaml` is) - except of the test file of course?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and the DartAnalyzer doesn't mark any of the related code as errors or warnings. All the files are located under /lib. Also I have all relevant class imported.

Comment: Then I don't know. You could try `pub get --packages-dir` perhaps you are using a ´test` version or whatever that doesn't work without the `packages` directory.

Comment: Possibly, but I create tons of objects within other classes within other classes. It must be something to do with generics. I may have a subtle misuse that I can recognize. I wish the analyzer could pick it up. I was just watching the strong mode video. I don't have strong mode enable though.

Comment: Perhaps some name collision within the same scope?

Comment: Argh! you were right Günter. I had a setter named the same as the class. The analyzer wasn't giving me a hint on that collision.

Comment: Glad to hear. Could you try to create a minimal reproduction (perhaps in https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) and create an issue in https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk to get it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a name collision. I have seen that the analyzer doesn't catch these in all cases.